# VBA Word - Apply a style to a line of text

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-style

I'm trying to apply a word style to a line of text using vba, so that it will appear in the table of contents.
I am having trouble keeping the style contained to the line in question though, for some reason the whole document is picking up the style.

```
With Selection
.TypeText Text:=headername                 ' This is defined previously,
.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdMove   ' This is to move the cursor to the start of the line
.Expand wdLine                           ' This is to select the whole line
.Style = "Heading 2"                     ' this is to define the style of the selected text
.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdMove      ' This is to unhighlight the text
.InsertBreak Type:=wdLineBreak            ' This is to create a line break    
 End With
```

For some reason though, the whole document picks up "Heading 2" as it's style.
I have tried countless other ways of doing this, but with no luck,

Does anyone know a better way of doing this, or see where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible to apply a paragraph style to a line of text, only. It must be applied to a paragraph. Sometimes, a paragraph occupies only a single line, as is likely the case in your scenario - but it's important to recognize the difference.

The problem with your code is that, given the order in which it performs the actions, inserting the break is picking up the style formatting and carrying it forward.

Much more efficient and clear is to work with Word's RANGE object, rather than the current Selection. You can use Selection as the starting point, but from then on your code should rely on the much more predictable Range (also, the user won't see things "jumping around"). For example:

```
Dim rng as Word.Range
Set rng = Selection.Range
rng.Text = headername & vbCr 'Insert the new para at same time
Set rng = rng.Paragraphs(1).Range 'Only the first para
rng.Style = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading2 'language independent
rng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd 
'focus in new para, which has different formatting
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I had tried to do this with paragraphs, but not in the way you had mentioned. I will try this shortly and get back to you.
Also, does rng.paragraphs(1).Range select the first paragraph of the selection, or the document?

I was under the impression it would be the document, which would unfortunately not help me, as this is part of a Loop that would generate multiple.

I'll it anyway, Thanks again for the help!

Comment: OK Thanks, the code to change the style of the paragraph works great, is there a way I can add the paragraph at the current point of the document, rather than always being at the top of the document.

I had tried paragraphs.add before, but didnt have too much luck.

Comment: I found a function which will get the number of a paragraph, So I have come up with a solution to find the number of the paragraph we just made, and then use this to define which paragraph we change the style of.

What do you think of this solution?
  ` Function GetParNum(r As Range) As Integer`
        Dim rParagraphs As Range
        Dim CurPos As Long
     
        r.Select
        CurPos = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\startOfSel").Start
        Set rParagraphs = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=0, End:=CurPos)
        GetParNum = rParagraphs.Paragraphs.Count
    End Function`

Sorry, Format Sucks

Comment: Paragraphs([index]) will return the paragraph index based on the object from which it depends. So it all depends in the above code what rng actually is. In this case, for applying the style, it will be the first paragraph that was in the Selection. Since we can't know what the Selection was, we can't know where it is in relation to the rest of the document without doing some kind of testing.

Comment: If you want to know in which paragraph your code currently is in relation to the entire body of the document, you can do something like this: Dim rngToDocStart : Set rngToDocStart = Document.Content : rngToDocStart.End = rng.End : rngToDocStart.Paragraphs.Count

Comment: Adding a paragraph at the current point is simple: Set rng = Selection.Range : rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd : rng.Text = vbCr

Comment: @CindyMeister Every time I have a Word VBA problem I find myself looking at a solution you posted years ago. Thank you! This time I was applying a style (that had PageBreakBefore true) to a paragraph. It worked with hotkey and clicking the style but not by applying the style in a macro. Thanks to your answer here this worked: `Set rng = Selection.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range` and `rng.style = ActiveDocument.Styles("H2 Break")`. Thank you again for making SO a great help.